# Can we customize the name and placement of the css file which contains the combined styles from all the Vue single file components?

Tags: vue.js, styles

As the file name is the same name as the main entry point script file. where our Vue instance resides. I wanted to explore the possibility of configuring it.

Comment: What are you using to build your app?

Comment: The styles you put in .vue files aren't put into a CSS file, they're added to your `<head>` at runtime. So no, you can't specify that kind of stuff. As far as I'm concerned using `<style>` in a .vue file is for development, but you should try to transfer it into proper SASS/LESS/CSS files when you're done, and make sure you use class names for everything, e.g. using a unique class name as a namespace for every component/page.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter It is a vue component inside symphony its an e-commerce application.

Comment: @SimonHyll actually it does create a css file in js folder inside public. and the name is same as the name of the file which has the vue instance. I wanted to customize the name and the created folder.